# MySQL databases mysterious table deletion

Tags: mysql, linux, system-administration

I need some advice on how to track down a weird occurence on one of my servers.  I'm not a linux expert so please bear with me if I haven't explained properly. We have a test server that is running apache, php5, mysql, postgresql on linux OS.  Recently the mysql database have had all tables removed apart from a few.  I've investigated the Apache, MySQL and website logs but can't spot anything odd. The server has sugarcrm, davical and drupal sites on there.

Is there something I can do to track the next time this happens?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Still looking into this and have found that the mysql.frm files have gone missing but not for all databases.

Also, as part of my investigation I ran dmesg | less to see if there's anything odd with machine

Answer (score 0):

You should activate query logging on your mysql server. In debian/ubuntu systems you can find the conf file my.cnf at "/etc/mysql/my.cnf". (I dont know which distribution you use)
Find the lines

```
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
```

and uncomment them deleting the "#"

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

restart the mysql server

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

you can see the changes in the log file from now on

note: You shouldnt use this on production server, or you may face some performance problems

Comment: I would recommend binary logging, not using the general log for this.